# JavaScript array.map always returning the last item

Tags: javascript, typescript, array-map

I have an array of objects, objects look like this:

```
interface IDog{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  summary: string;
  wikiLink: string;
  imageLink: string;
  imageAlt: string;
}
```

I have this function:

```
  private processDog(dogs: IDog[]) {
  return dogs.map((dog) => {
      let displayCard = this.dogDisplay;

      find(displayCard.body, { id: "cardHeader" }).items[0].text = dog.name;
      let adaptiveCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(displayCard);

      let preview = this.dogPreview;
      preview.content.title = dog.name;
     
      return { ...adaptiveCard, preview };
    });
  }
```

Now when I call this function, passing an array of Dogs, let's say [DogA, DogB, DogC, DogD]

```
    let att = this.processDog(dogs);
```

I am expecting to return an array of the processed dogs as needed, however what's returned is an array of 4 processed dogs of type DogD.. meaning that DogD is shadowing all other dogs in the returned array. What am I doing wrong?

Full code:

```
//First method
      public async onQuery(
        context: TurnContext,
        query: MessagingExtensionQuery
      ): Promise<MessagingExtensionResult> {
     
     const dogs: any = require("./dogs.json");
     let att = this.processdog(dogs);
     console.log(att);
     return Promise.resolve({
            type: "result",
            attachmentLayout: "list",
            attachments: att, // [{ ...adaptiveCard, preview: defaultPreview }],
          } as MessagingExtensionResult);
    }

//second method

 private processdog(dogs: Idog[]) {
  return dogs.map((dog) => {
      let displayCard = Object.assign({}, this.dogDisplayCard);

      find(displayCard.body, { id: "cardHeader" }).items[0].text = dog.name;
      find(displayCard.body, { id: "cardBody" }).items[0].text = dog.summary;
      find(displayCard.body, {
        id: "cardBody",
      }).items[1].columns[0].items[0].url = dog.imageLink;
      find(displayCard.body, { id: "cardBody" }).items[2].text = dog.imageAlt;
      displayCard.actions[0].url = dog.wikiLink;
      let adaptiveCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(displayCard);

      let preview = Object.assign({}, this.dogPreviewCard);

      preview.content.title = dog.name;
      preview.content.text = dog.imageAlt;
      preview.content.images[0].url = dog.imageLink;

      return { ...adaptiveCard, preview };
    });
  }
```

dogPreview.json:

```
{
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
"content": {
  "title": "",
  "text": "",
  "images": [
    {
      "url": ""
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Have you logged and checked that your input is correct and not just the same Dog?

Comment: Can you clarify what this line does find(displayCard.body, { id: "cardHeader" }).items[0].text = dog.name;

Comment: @Mark , yeah I added console.log just before the return statement in my function, and I can see that they are different values.. but when the map is finished, they're all the same

Comment: @PhilCowan , so I am using an adaptive card, I am using the find function from lodash to get the object of id "cardHeader" inside the body, and setting a text to dog.name

Comment: You likely need to copy `this.dogDisplay` and `this.dogPreview`, probably with `Object.assign({}, this.dogDisplay)` and `Object.assign({}, this.dogPreview)`

Comment: @iz_ can you share the full syntax please?

Comment: nevermind I think I got it @iz_

Comment: Can you also share your full code with definitions of `this.dogDisplay` and `this.dogPreview`? It seems strange how you are using them.

Comment: @iz_ no that didn't work :(

Comment: @iz_ just updated the full code in the question

Comment: Seems like you need to make a deep copy. What do `this.dogDisplayCard` and `this.dogPreviewCard` look like?

Comment: @iz_ these are JSON files, I pasted an example now for the dogPreivew.json

Comment: Instead of loading JSON files, I would create a factory function that returns a new copy of that object. If you want to stay with your current structure, try `let displayCard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dogDisplayCard));` and same for `previewCard`.

Comment: let me try it out @iz_

Comment: whoa! that worked!!!! but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a deep copy of your objects like so

```
...
let displayCard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dogDisplayCard));
...
let preview = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dogPreviewCard));
...
```

Otherwise, you will be mutating the original object with the lines that follow. `{ ...adaptiveCard, preview }` will contain references to the original object, so will update when the original object does. So, you must ensure that you are working with a fresh copy of the object that does not have any references to the original object.

Comment: you dont really need a DeepClone like using JSON.stringify/JSON.parse
using `{...this.dogDisplayCard}` or `Object.assign({}, this.dogDisplayCard)` would both work just fine, but a LOT cheaper

Comment: Also, neither preview nor displayCard are modified, so you can use const, instead of let

Comment: @AlexandreDias No, deep cloning is necessary because they are nested objects. Check the comments on the question; I already suggested shallow cloning.

Comment: you're right, I was looking at the Dog Interface :P